# Stop build execution in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins to run a Maven project having Junit tests in Sauce Connect. I created a job and to stop/abort the build in between I clicked the Cross button (X) shown near progress bar for build execution. But the build execution does not get stopped.
When I moved to console output for the build, it was showing message as "Closing Sauce Connect" and it takesd too much time and Jenkins does not stop build process.

Could anyone please advice as to how can we manually stop/abort build execution.

Additionally, is there any site where we can find proper documentation regarding Jenkins for Beginners as i have few more problems regarding its start and stop process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jenkins will terminate the build nicely, i.e. wait for the running processes to end after sending the termination signal. If the processes take a long time to terminate, it will wait. The easiest way is to change your build/code such that it terminates immediately, or has a timeout for closing connections etc.

Regarding more documentation, have a look at the [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins) or get the [Jenkins book](http://www.wakaleo.com/books/jenkins-the-definitive-guide).

Comment: Lars, actually I am not invoking Sauce Connect. Jenkins is creating Sauce connect session so how can I update my tests to close Sauce Connect. Please advice.

Comment: I haven't used Sauce Connect, but I would imagine that there's something that allows you to specify a timeout or something along those lines.

Answer (score 5):

I guess it is too late to answer but my help some people.

1. Install the monitoring plugin. (http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring)
2. Go to jenkinsUrl/monitoring/nodes
3. Go to the Threads section at the bottom
4. Click on the details buttom on the left of the slave the job is build on
5. Sort by User time (ms)
6. Then look at the name of the thread, you will have the name and number of the build
7. Kill it

Hope it can help

Comment: You can jump directy to thread list with:
    `<jenkinsUrl>/monitoring?part=threads`
then continue with point 5.

Comment: can someone show the steps to do this programmatically?